# CSS Transform at chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I've created simply hover animation using CSS and some Jquery. All works fine until chrome get updated. Now transformed element is half after content and half before, link to demo site: http://demo.pandaart.pl/wp/gemini/ On firefox it works fine. On IE same problem as chrome.

Here is my CSS:

```
#home_boxes{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
    display: table;
    width:1170px;
}
#home_boxes .item {
    float: left;
    width: 370px; height: 250px;    
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
}
#home_boxes .box .opis{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    width:100%;
    left:0; bottom: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    z-index: 1;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    text-align: center;
}
#home_boxes .box .opis .bg{
    background: #dd2a1b;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    left:0;top:0;
    display: block;
    z-index: -1;
}
#home_boxes .box .content{
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #FFF;
    opacity: 0;
}

#home_boxes .box {
    float: left;
    width: 370px; height: 250px;    
    display: block;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 7px solid #442321;
    border-radius: 7px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.18, 0.89, 0.32, 1);
}
#home_boxes .box.open{
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: 520px;
    z-index: 1002;
    transition: all 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.18, 0.89, 0.32, 1.3);
}
#home_boxes .item:nth-of-type(2) .box.open{
    margin-left: -390px;
}
#home_boxes .item:nth-of-type(3) .box.open{
    margin-left: -780px;
}
#home_boxes .item:nth-of-type(4) .box.open{
    margin-top:-270px;
}
#home_boxes .item:nth-of-type(5) .box.open{
    margin-top:-270px;
    margin-left: -390px;
}
#home_boxes .item:nth-of-type(6) .box.open{
    margin-top:-270px;
    margin-left: -780px;
}
#home_boxes .box .okladki{
    opacity: 0;
    width:100%; height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transform:rotateY(0deg);
    transition:transform .3s ease-in-out;
    transform-style:preserve-3d;
    cursor: pointer;
}  
#home_boxes .box.open .content{
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}
#home_boxes .box:not(.open) .okladki{    
    opacity: 1;
}
#home_boxes .box .okladki > div {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;     
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
#home_boxes .box .front {
    transform:translateZ(40px);
}
#home_boxes .box .back {
    background: #3B5998; font-size: 3em;
    transform:rotateY(-100deg) translateZ(40px);
}
#home_boxes .box .okladki:hover {
    transform: rotateY(100deg);
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks for comments ;)

Comment: Can you make a smaller example, in codepen or something, that demonstrates the issue? Also, which exact update of Chrome made the problem happen? I mean, in which version was it still OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated some of css worked fine for me

```
#home_boxes .box .okladki:hover {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
#home_boxes .box .front {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(40px);
}
#home_boxes .box .back {
  background: #3B5998;
  font-size: 3em;
  transform: rotateY(-180deg) translateZ(40px);
}
```

you can refer http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip for more details

Answer (score 0):

Updated the value of `translateZ(180px)` in the below class, add the below code and try.

```
#home_boxes .box .back {
    background: #3B5998; font-size: 3em;
    transform:rotateY(-100deg) translateZ(180px);
}
```